# Ruby http-post with blank path

Tags: ruby, windows-8

I need to do a HTTP-POST to Windows-Notification-SERVER.

The URL is https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AgUAAAADoGlaM0THo74Q%2bJP7MkgBEJzYC7OyTwh59QmECe9MgwfwGSWLsMhkG%2bHF3JI3q3gySjc3keErqcwWYCN9Qwi2z7TdCMnYGb30huMkKrzB54%2fH73vxrYzp36SQScHazJA%3d

But, the code id throwing back a 404 error. I suspect, if its the EMPTY-PATH that's causing it.

Can someone please help me out.

Here is my Ruby code : https://gist.github.com/2308226

Here is the Object-C implementation of the same code (see the SendPush method) : https://gist.github.com/2235318

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the ?token=... part of the URL. I haven't checked, but I suspect that is the problem.

```
  uri = URI.parse("http://google.com:1337/foo/bar?token=1")
  uri.host.should == "google.com"
  uri.port.should == 1337
  uri.path.should == "/foo/bar"
  uri.query.should == "token=1"
```

In line #34 of your Gist, you are using just the `uri.path` when you should be using:

```
"#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}"
```